# How can a batch-file set a build task error?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Our Azure DevOps pipeline includes some legacy batch-file steps. These involve copying files from place to place and if files are missing, the task still shows as succeeding in DevOps - I have to search the logs for messages afterwards - and the rest of the pipeline steps continue.

Is it possible to have a failed file-copy marked as either a error or warning on the task in some way?

Comment: Return a non-zero exit code if the batch file fails.

Comment: @DanielMann that's the point, the batch file doesn't fail. It just has a load of copy/xcopy statements... I am very rusty on my .BAT coding, can I detect an error at the end of the script without making loads of changes (this script is pre-existing and ideally not modified)